# Opencart Showing No of Page result text beside pagination

Tags: opencart2.x

I am new at opencart and using version 2.2.0.0 , I want to change `no of page text` *example*-`(Showing 1 to 15 of 31 (3 Pages))` beside `pagination link` in category page.How to do that ? any idea

thanks
[Pls see the text example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmQFH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your default language is `English`.

Go to `catalog/language/english/default.php`.

Search for the text `$_['text_pagination'] = 'Showing %d to %d of %d (%d Pages)';` and change it as per you like.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. However I am using opencart 2.2.0.0 and I found it in catalog/language/en-gb/en-gb.php . Thanks

Comment: My bad. I'm sorry mate. :)

Comment: I tried but it tells me that it will require 15 reputation which i don't have. Can u help me with this issue pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540543/bootstrap-and-css-custom-checkbox-after-page-postback